# My rear license plate is loose because of a missing screw

Tags: honda, accord, screw, license-plates

I had to remove a rusted screw in order to replace my rear license plate on my Honda Accord but in doing so, I tore off some of the surrounding material near the hole the screw fits in. My license plate is hanging there with the other screw and some Velcro so a permanent fix is needed but I'm unsure of what to do. As if I attempt to put a screw in the hole with the torn material, it doesn't tighten therefore is useless for holding in the license plate. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the screw was just screwed into fibreglass, then a simple fibreglass patch is all you need. Cover the hole, and then once it has set, drill a pilot hole and fit the new screw.

Alternatively you could use a couple of washers and a bolt, rather than a screw.

Because this is not a high load, and is hidden in normal use, you don't need anything that clever or complicated.